# Accessing Date type attribute failing randomly while looping through array of core data objects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a coredata entity with attributes name (String) and date (Date). I added 500 records.

While looping through the NSManagedObjects to access the name attribute - works fine.

This code works

```
for transaction in self.transactions 
{
   print(transaction.value(forKeyPath:"name") as! String)
}
```

But while looping through the objects to access the date attribute - it fails randomly with error message "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

This code fails.

```
for transaction in self.transactions 
{
    print(transaction.value(forKeyPath: "date") as! Date)
}
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are force unwrapping it even whilst uncertain that the value's type is "Date" or "String" instead you should safely try to unwrap it like such:

```
for transaction in self.transactions {
    if let date = transaction.value(forKeyPath: "date") as? Date {
         print("It's a date: \(date)")
    } else if stringValue = transaction.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String {
         print("It's a string: \(stringValue)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are storing correct date in core data.